# page not found error while passing paarmeter through url in view django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am new to python django. I am facing an issue while passing parameter to view through URL in django. 
code:
    views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
   text = "HEllo"
   return HttpResponse(text)

def viewArticle(request, articleId):
   text = "HEllo : %d"%articleId
   return HttpResponse(text)


urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path,include
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
path('hello/',views.hello,name='hello'),
path('article/(\d

+)/',views.viewArticle,name='article'),

]
```

image:[image]

Comment: Your url should be __article__/42, not __atricle__/42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your url like this:

```
path('article/<int:articleId>/',views.viewArticle,name='article'),
```

Hope this work!

Answer (score 0):

Here your are using [**path**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path). And path uses route without regex.

You need to change url to,

```
path('article/<int:articleId>/',views.viewArticle,name='article'),
```